# Spring cloud contract stubs not found in my local repo

Tags: java, maven-3, spring-cloud-contract

Using Spring Cloud Contract 1.0.2.RELEASE, I'm able to publish the stubs in my local Maven repo, but they are not found by the consumer side when I run the tests.

It looks like on the consumer side, it picks a different location for local maven repo than what the producer has : despite good logging by Spring Cloud Contract and Aether libraries, it took me a while to figure it out, as the location I used for local Maven repo is similar (but different) to the default one.

I'm using Maven 3.3.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.AetherFactories , we see clearly that it gets the local repository location like this :

```
private static final String MAVEN_LOCAL_REPOSITORY_LOCATION = "maven.repo.local";

private static String localRepositoryDirectory() {
    return System.getProperty(MAVEN_LOCAL_REPOSITORY_LOCATION, System.getProperty("user.home") + "/.m2/repository");
}
```

So if you're overriding the local Maven repo location in your Maven settings.xml using something like this :

```
<localRepository>C:/HOMEWARE/maven_local_repo</localRepository>
```

your producer will install the stubs in this location, but the consumer will look in the default location for local repo, **unless you define yourself the location through "maven.repo.local" system property**.

You can do it like this using surefire on consumer side :

```
<build>
    ...
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <maven.repo.local>${settings.localRepository}</maven.repo.local>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Thanks for this explanation, I think Spring Cloud Contracts should search stubs in **~/.m2/reposiroty** by default, **not** according to *maven.repo.local* settings ,  but it seems it was searching **<project folder>/${user.home}/.m2/repository** instead in my project if I dont set **maven.repo.local**.